# Aurelia force dirty checking without getter

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to conditionally add a class to an element based on the result of a function call, but Aurelia won't re-run the function when its parameters change. Normally I'd use a getter to force dirty checking but since my function needs arguments that isn't possible.

The function in question looks like this:

```js
isVisible (item, filters) {
    // If there are no filters selected, or at least one of the item's tag names are inside the filters the item is considered visible
    return (!filters.length || (filters.length && item.tags.some(tag => {
        return filters.indexOf(tag.name) !== -1 ? true : false;
    })));
}
```

And in case it's not obvious it takes an `item` and an array of strings (`filters`) and then checks if any of `item.tags[].name` is inside the array of `filters`.

It is used in my view like so:

```html
<item repeat.for="item of items" item.bind="item" class="${isVisible(item, filters) ? 'show' : 'hide'}"></item>
```

I also tried just adding the code directly to the view which I assume will force Aurelia to re-calculate things but when adding the entirety of the function's code to the view (inside a `${code here}`) I get parse error unexpected `>`.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.sobell.net/aurelia-dirty-checking-a-function/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your above example is enough to have it re-evaluated whenever `filters` changed. However, if you mutate `filters`, Aurelia won't be able to pick up the change as array observation is not automatic for performance reason. You can work around this by using immutable instances of `filters` or additionally observe `filters` length like the following:

```html
<item repeat.for="item of items"
    item.bind="item"
    class="${isVisible(item, filters, filters.length) ? 'show' : 'hide'></item>
```

Comment: Nice, simply passing in `filters.length` did the trick! I understand why, even though it does feel like a bit of a hack...

Comment: A question, in reality the `filters` array is actually available inside my VM, so passing it from my view isn't strictly necessary. Is there any way I could achieve the same result when only passing in `item`; `isVisible(item)`? Is there a decorator or something I could use on the VM's `isVisible` method?

Comment: What you are curious about is method observation, that is currently unsupported. I guess best you can do is to use a signal and every time you change the `filters`, signal the `repeat` bindings to reevaluate.